# IOS Swipe Back gesture does not perfom navigation.goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6

I have a drawer navigator with many child navigators.
On Android, both Header back arrow and navigation bar back button work and go back to previous screens.
E.g., if I navigate to a bScreen1 through the drawer, both buttons get me back to the Home Screen of the App i.e. aScreen1

On IOS, Header back arrow work fine, HOWEVER, swipe back gets me back to my login screen inside the AuthNavigator instead of aScreen1, which has 0 sens to me because it is outside the drawerNavigator, and at the same level inside the RootNavigator. The swipe back does not perform a navigation.goBack().

I have already tried overriding the swipe behavior by adding a listener on 'beforeRemove' event and then calling navigation.goBack(), but the wrong screen still shows up for a instant before moving to the right one (previous one)

```
...
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();
const rootStack = createStackNavigator();

...
drawerNavigator() {
 return (
  <DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
    <DrawerNavigator.Screen component={aNavigator} />
    <DrawerNavigator.Screen component={bNavigator} />
    ...
    <DrawerNavigator.Screen component={zNavigator} />
  </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
)}

aNavigator() {
return (
  <ANavigator.Navigator>
    <ANavigator.Screen component={aScreen1} />
    ...
    <ANavigator.Screen component={aScreen10} />
  </ANavigator.Navigator>
)}

bNavigator() {
return (
  <ANavigator.Navigator>
    <ANavigator.Screen component={bScreen1} />
    ...
    <ANavigator.Screen component={bScreen10} />
  </ANavigator.Navigator>
)}


 <rootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="AuthNavigator" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
       <rootStack.Screen name="AuthNavigator" component={createAuthNavigator} />
       <rootStack.Screen name="DrawerNavigator" component={drawerNavigator} />
</rootStack.Navigator>
```

Ps: I am using all the latest versions of navigation packages

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me not even the back swipe works.

Comment: I have solved the issue where the swipe back gesture took me back to the login screen by using conditional rendering of my navigators and handling signing inside the App root component. Basically, when the user is signed in, you render one navigator, and when not, you render the auth navigator (meaning you login screen and other related screens)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I set `animationEnabled: false`, if you set it to `true` you should be able to swipe to switch screens.

Comment: The swipe is performed, the problem is that is does not go to the previous screen like done by navigation.goBack()